# Как найти все теги button на странице?

Tags: javascript

Как присвоить все найденные однотипные элементы (например, `button`) и присвоить их переменной, чтобы **`ВНЕ ЦИКЛА`** я мог задать другой фон кнопкам? например:

http://jsbin.com/gopufewive/edit?html,js,output

```js
//-- находим и присваиваем переменной  
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('button'),
    btns;

//-- перебираем и присваиваем все кнопки одной переменной
for (var i = 0, all = btn.length; i < all; i++) {
  btns = btn[i];
  btns.style.color = 'red';
}

//-- добавляем всем кнопкам фон???
btns.style.background = "black";
```

Comment: На мой взгляд, вопрос интересный. В C#, например, можно добавить метод к существующему закрытому классу без наследования. Как в JS - не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

```
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('button'),
btns;
var button;
 for (var i=0, all=btn.length; i<all; i++){
   btn[i].style.color = 'red';
   if(i == 2) { // ваше условие, я обращаюсь к второй кнопке
      button = btn[i];
   }
}
 button.style.color = 'green';
```